# Does anyone have a definitive list of how Node's require paths work?

Tags: node.js, require

I see the following...

```
'./folder/'
'../folder/'
'folder/'
'/folder/'
```

Can anyone explain the different path types? Also is there a way to just autosearch all folders? Refactoring is a pain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exact filename is not found, then node will attempt to load the required filename with the added extension of *.js*, *.json*, and then *.node*.

*.js* files are interpreted as JavaScript text files, and *.json* files are parsed as JSON text files. *.node* files are interpreted as compiled addon modules loaded with *dlopen*.

A module prefixed with '/' is an absolute path to the file. For example, require('/home/marco/foo.js') will load the file at /home/marco/foo.js.

A module prefixed with *'./'* is relative to the file calling *require()*. That is, *circle.js* must be in the same directory as *foo.js* for *require('./circle')* to find it.

Without a leading *'/'* or *'./'* to indicate a file, the module is either a "core module" or is loaded from a *node_modules* folder.

If the given path does not exist, *require()* will throw an Error with its *code* property set to *'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'*.

Extracted from https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a native module,
>   and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then node starts at the
>   parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and
>   attempts to load the module from that location.
>
> If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the file system is reached.